# ¿Existen verbos para los cuales no existan sustantivos abstractos relacionados?

Tags: verbos, sustantivos

Para responder [esta pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/28277/los-infinitivos-son-sustantivos/28278#28278) me costó bastante trabajo encontrar un verbo para el cual el sustantivo no indique normalmente la acción correspondiente. Si bien "madrugada" puede significar la acción de madrugar, normalmente usamos esa palabra para referirnos a las horas antes del amanecer.

Tengo dos preguntas:

- ¿Existen verbos que directamente no tengan sustantivos relacionados para hacer referencia a las acciones correspondientes?
- ¿Existen verbos para los cuales existan sustantivos de otra raíz (o que sean al menos muy diferentes del verbo) que denoten las acciones correspondientes?

Comment: Muy divertido el otro día cuando estábamos en casa y mi hijo mayor quiso decir que quería pelar él la mandarina, pero prefirió usar el sustantivo y en vez de "[peladura](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SMS3W6l)" dijo que quería "hacer la pelación".

Comment: Yo diría que el verbo _ser_ no tiene sustantivo asociado. También posiblemente el verbo _hacer_, y tampoco encuentro sustantivo para _efectuar_. Diría también el verbo _estar_ pero creo que _estancia_ (permanencia en un lugar determinado) podría ser su sustantivo asociado.

Comment: @Charlie Tal vez debería limitar la pregunta a verbos que no tengan sustantivos abstractos asociados. De todos los verbos que mencionas el mejor ejemplo creo que es *efectuar*: "efecto" está relacionado pero no tiene mucho que ver semánticamente. Para los otros verbos, tenemos los sustantivos *ser, hecho, estadía* (o "estancia", como dices).

Comment: No me queda claro que entre "ser" (sustantivo) y "ser" (verbo) y entre "hecho" y "hacer" haya la misma relación que entre "peladura" y "pelar". Me refiero a peladura en su acepción de "acción y efecto de pelar", no a la de "monda, cáscara" (lo que queda después de la peladura).

Comment: @Charlie Tienes razón con respecto a "hecho". No estoy seguro si "el ser" como sinónimo de existencia (en filosofía) es sustantivo o verbo antecedido por artículo, como "el andar". Me parece que es lo segundo. "el ser" sustantivo se referirá a una criatura, como en "el ser humano", "los seres extraterrestres".

Comment: Creo que para "hacer" el sustantivo correspondiente es "acto" o "acción" (ejercicio de la posibilidad de hacer). Para "ser" no lo tengo claro aún, y me surge otro: "parecer".

Comment: @Charlie Puedes ir armando una respuesta si quieres (el ejemplo de "acto/acción" como sustantivo de "hacer" es muy bueno). Me parece que "el parecido" puede referirse al "hecho de parecerse", y "la apariencia" al "hecho de parecer".

Comment: Quizá debería limitarse más todavía la pregunta: por lo que parece, todos estamos pensando en verbos de acción (con sujeto agente) porque los otros son muy complicados de pensar. :)

Comment: @Charlie No me queda claro porqué descartas "hecho". Nótese que en su cuarta acepción incluso es sinónimo de "acción", una de las dos que mencionas.

Comment: @RubioRic porque entiendo que "hecho" es el resultado de "hacer", y no el acto de "hacer". Pero que tampoco lo descartaba, solo decía que no lo veía claro, me encanta que la gente me rebata y me haga aprender cosas nuevas. :)

Answer (score 4):

Como verbos que no tengan sustantivos relacionados para expresar su acción, tenemos que irnos a lo más básico: el verbo *[ser](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Xe5Brrm%7CXe5NPsQ)*. Se podría argumentar que la propia palabra *ser* como sustantivo es su propia acción, pero yo personalmente no lo tengo claro. Una de las acepciones de *ser*, "existir", sí podría tener un sustantivo de acción: *[existencia](http://dle.rae.es/?id=HFqUbfY)*, que es el acto de existir, aunque esto no cubre todas las demás acepciones de *ser*. Argumentan por [La Tertulia](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/48441213#48441213) que su sustantivo podría ser *[esencia](http://dle.rae.es/?id=GOfryI4)*, pero no aparece en el DLE con el significado de "acto de ser" o similar. ¿Tal vez en latín sí tenía ese significado?

Tampoco tengo claro que el verbo *haber* tenga su acción correspondiente, claro que por sí solo como verbo auxiliar no tiene mucho sentido, y con otros significados tenemos *tenencia* o *posesión* en su acepción de "poseer", *acontecimiento* en su acepción de "ocurrir" o "acontencer", etc. Similar al caso de *ser* es el de *poder*, existe el sustantivo *poder* pero no tengo claro que indique el acto de poder. ¿Tal ver *[potencia](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Trbc5zu)* sería su sustantivo de acción?

Y luego como sustantivo con una raíz diferente del verbo tenemos *hacer*, que tiene un sustantivo en *[acto](http://dle.rae.es/?id=0cnCBhK)* o en *[acción](http://dle.rae.es/?id=0KZwLbE)*, que es el "ejercicio de la posibilidad de hacer".

Answer (score 2):

Por el mero hecho de saber hablar español podemos inventar un sustantivo a partir de un verbo, agregando un sufijo adecuado como -ción, -miento o -ada. Otra cosa es que esa palabra esté integrada a la lengua.

El verbo ***llorar*** se asocia al sustantivo *llanto*, pero (creo), uno no se deriva del otro. Lo normal sería en cambio hablar de "una *llorada*", que es algo fácilmente inventable y comprensible, pero según el diccionario sólo lo han adoptado en Colombia y Guatemala.

Igual cosa con el verbo ***largar*** (que significa "liberar"). Según el diccionario, *largada* es propio solo de argentinos y uruguayos. No existen la *largación*, el *largamiento*, la *larganza* ni la *largancia* para referirse a "liberación". *Largo* y *alargamiento* son otra cosa, tienen que ver con la longitud.

Comment: Bien, Rodrigo. Me gustaron tus dos ejemplos.